# Activate User Account - Email

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm try to make a user register & activate their account via email. Email is success sended, link confirm is success clicked and it say ' Activations success' as i set. But the 'status' on database wont change. Can someone help me ? Whats wrong with this code.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Voter_model extends CI_Model
{


    function __construct()
    {
         // Call the Model constructor
         parent::__construct();
    }

    //get the username & password from tbl_usrs
    function get_user($username, $password)
    {
         $sql = "select * from user where username = '" . $username . "' and password = '" . $password . "' and status = '1'";
         $query = $this->db->query($sql);
         return $query->num_rows();
    }


     //insert into user table
   function insertUser($data)
   {
       return $this->db->insert('user', $data);
   }

   //send verification email to user's email id
   function sendEmail($to_email)
   {
       $from_email = 'evotingcucukan@gmail.com'; //change this to yours
       $subject = 'Aktivasi Akun';
       $message = 'Hallo'. $username .'<br /><br />Silakan klik link dibawah ini untuk mengkonfirmasi akun Anda pada Sistem E-voting Desa Pakraman Cucukan.<br /><br /> 
 '. site_url('voter/voter_register/verify/'.md5($to_email)) . '<br /><br /><br />Terima Kasih<br />Admin Evoting';

       //configure email settings
       $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
       $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com'; //smtp host name
       $config['smtp_port'] = '465'; //smtp port number
       $config['smtp_user'] = $from_email;
       $config['smtp_pass'] = 'evoting2016'; //$from_email password
       $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
       $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
       $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
       $config['newline'] = "\r\n"; //use double quotes
       $this->email->initialize($config);

       //send mail
       $this->email->from($from_email, 'Admin Evoting');
       $this->email->to($to_email);
       $this->email->subject($subject);
       $this->email->message($message);
       return $this->email->send();
   }

   //activate user account
   function verifyEmailID($key)
    {
   $data = array('status' => 1);
   $this->db->where('email', $key);
   $verify=$this->db->update('user', $data);
    if($verify==true) 
         {
          return true;
        }
          return false;
    }



}?>
```

and My Controller is,

```
<?php
class Voter_register extends CI_Controller
{
   public function __construct()
   {
       parent::__construct();
       $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
       $this->load->library(array('session', 'form_validation', 'email'));
       $this->load->database();
       $this->load->model('Voter_model');
   }

   function index()
   {
       $this->register();
   }



   function register()
   {
       //set validation rules

       $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email ID', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[user.email]');
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|matches[cpassword]');
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword', 'Confirm Password', 'trim|required');

       //validate form input
       if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
       {
           // fails
           $this->load->view('voter/voter_register');
       }
       else
       {
           //insert the user registration details into database
           $data = array(
               'fname' => $this->input->post('fname'),
               'lname' => $this->input->post('lname'),
               'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
               'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
                 'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                 'voting'=> 1


           );

           // insert form data into database
           if ($this->Voter_model->insertUser($data))
           {
               // send email
               if ($this->Voter_model->sendEmail($this->input->post('email')))
               {
                   // successfully sent mail
                   $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Registrasi Sukses, silakan cek e-mail Anda untuk melakukan konfirmasi dan aktivasi akun.</div>');
                   redirect('admin_voter');
               }
               else
               {
                   // error
                   $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-info text-center">Registrasi Sukses, gagal mengirim e-mail verifikasi.</div>');
                   redirect('admin_voter');
               }
           }
           else
           {
               // error
               $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Oops! Error.  Please try again later!!!</div>');
               redirect('admin_voter');
           }
       }
   }

   function verify($hash)
   {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->model('voter_model');

       if ($this->voter_model->verifyEmailID($hash))
       {

          redirect('voter/voter_aktivasiok');
       }
       else
       {

           redirect('voter/voter_aktivasifail');
       }
   }
}
?>
```

Thank you for anything help.

Comment: Break the code into steps, returning true on each step, you will then find out where is the problem. Also use strict If statements to check whether it effect the end results or not

Answer (score 0):

You do the encrypt MD5

```
md5($to_email))
```

Add the `urlencode()` also

You don't decrypt MD5..

```
function verify($hash)
   {

        $hash =  base64_decode(urldecode($hash));

        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->model('voter_model');

       if ($this->voter_model->verifyEmailID($hash))
       {

          redirect('voter/voter_aktivasiok');
       }
       else
       {

           redirect('voter/voter_aktivasifail');
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Error Number: 1267

Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='

UPDATE `user` SET `status` = 1 WHERE `email` = '�ޞw����}ѭ=�޻i����:�^�'

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/evotingcucukan/application/models/Voter_model.php

Line Number: 61

Answer (score 0):

Update the model "activationAccount" function with the following code :-

   <?php 
  /* activate user account */
   function verifyEmailID($key)
    {
   $data = array('status' => 1);
   $this->db->where('MD5(email)', $key, FALSE);
   $verify=$this->db->update('user', $data);
    if($verify==true) 
         {
          return true;
        }
          return false;
    }
  }
?>

Comment: Dear, Senthil .

I tried it, but doesnt work. Still error . T.T

Comment: Error Number: 1054

Unknown column '6d6ed6fb6b990a099d67af6b1986916e' in 'where clause'

UPDATE `user` SET `status` = 1 WHERE MD5(email) = 6d6ed6fb6b990a099d67af6b1986916e

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/evotingcucukan/application/models/Voter_model.php

Line Number: 61

Comment: /* Use backtick symbol inside the double quotes of value */                     $this->db->where('MD5(email)', "\`$key\`", FALSE);